# Text missing when minimising window

Tags: html, css

Text is missing when minimising window.

The text is going through the sides of the window instead of wrapping downwards.
Try to run the code full window, and then adjust the window width, and see what I mean.

I cannot find the solution, could you please help?

**Here is what it should look like** when minimised

[image]

**Here is fiddle link :**  https://jsfiddle.net/zgLtbvyv/

```css
/*everything is in a column*/
.mb-flex-column{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
}
    
  
/*image and text are in a row*/
  .mb-flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
      align-content: center;
}    
/*Flex to aligne the image and text correctly, and make them stick to the side*/
.mb-flex-item:nth-child(odd) .mb-flex-row{
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

.mb-content-wrap{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
.mb-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;  
    }
    
h4{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=mb-gara-mobile>
    <div class="mb-flex-column black">
                <div class="mb-flex-item">
                    <div class="mb-flex-row">
                        <div class="image-wrap">
                            <img src="svg/gara1.svg"  alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                            <div class="mb-content">
                                <h4>Fornøydsgaranti</h4>
                                   De to første øktene er gratis, og du kan kanslerere når du vil.
                                    Fornøydsgarantien gjelder alle elever.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="mb-flex-item">
             <div class="mb-flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="svg/gara2.svg"   alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                    <div class="mb-content">
                        <h4>Karaktergaranti</h4>
                        Jeg refunderer 100% av totalbeløpet dersom jeg feiler med å  forbedre karakteren til eleven. Gjelder for elever med startkarkater: 2, 3 eller 4.
                        Karaktergarantien gjelder kun for elever som har hatt mer enn 15 timer med med meg. 
                    </div>
                </div>           
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="mb-flex-item">
            <div class="mb-flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="svg/gara3.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                    <div class="mb-content">
                        <h4>Oppfølgingsgaranti</h4>
                        Hver lørdag fra kl 0800-1200 setter jeg av en halvtime per elev til oppfølging. I stedet for å møte en gang hver uke, møtes vi to ganger i uken.  Oppfølgingen er gratis. Oppfølgingsgarantien gjelder for alle elever.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing `.mb-content-wrap { display: table; }` to `.mb-content-wrap { display: block; }` help for me: https://jsfiddle.net/zgLtbvyv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change in your css:

```
.mb-content-wrap {
    /*display:table;*/
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alaa Mh. That is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*everything is in a column*/
.mb-flex-column{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
}
    
  
/*image and text are in a row*/
  .mb-flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
      align-content: center;
}    
/*Flex to aligne the image and text correctly, and make them stick to the side*/
.mb-flex-item:nth-child(odd) .mb-flex-row{
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

.mb-content-wrap{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
.mb-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;  
    }
    
h4{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=mb-gara-mobile>
    <div class="mb-flex-column black">
                <div class="mb-flex-item">
                    <div class="mb-flex-row">
                        <div class="image-wrap">
                            <img src="http://mathsmattersresources.com/wp-content/uploads/Right-Angle-Triangle-Blue-John-Duffield1.png"  alt="" style="height:50px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                            <div class="mb-content">
                                <h4>Fornøydsgaranti</h4>
                                   De to første øktene er gratis, og du kan kanslerere når du vil.
                                    Fornøydsgarantien gjelder alle elever.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="mb-flex-item">
             <div class="mb-flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://mathsmattersresources.com/wp-content/uploads/Right-Angle-Triangle-Blue-John-Duffield1.png" alt="" style="height:50px">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                    <div class="mb-content">
                        <h4>Karaktergaranti</h4>
                        Jeg refunderer 100% av totalbeløpet dersom jeg feiler med å  forbedre karakteren til eleven. Gjelder for elever med startkarkater: 2, 3 eller 4.
                        Karaktergarantien gjelder kun for elever som har hatt mer enn 15 timer med med meg. 
                    </div>
                </div>           
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="mb-flex-item">
            <div class="mb-flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://mathsmattersresources.com/wp-content/uploads/Right-Angle-Triangle-Blue-John-Duffield1.png" alt="" style="height:50px">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-content-wrap">
                    <div class="mb-content">
                        <h4>Oppfølgingsgaranti</h4>
                        Hver lørdag fra kl 0800-1200 setter jeg av en halvtime per elev til oppfølging. I stedet for å møte en gang hver uke, møtes vi to ganger i uken.  Oppfølgingen er gratis. Oppfølgingsgarantien gjelder for alle elever.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```